# How do I parallelize externalNativeBuild for different ABIs?

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, ninja

**Background**

I'm currently working on an Android project which contains a fair amount of native code. The native code is built for multiple ABIs. For various reasons, the native code has up until now been built using a custom Gradle task that invokes `ndk-build.cmd`.

Now I'm in the process of changing this to use `externalNativeBuild` for the NDK integration, and CMake lists instead of the old `Android.mk` files. It seems like the better supported/documented way of doing things.

---

**Problem**

One nice thing about the old `ndk-build` method was that it would build for multiple ABIs in parallel - e.g. an ARM version and an x86 version of the library could be built in parallel.
This is especially helpful in my case, because I am required to use a 3rd party tool during the linking phase which 1) takes a very long time (minutes) to finish, and 2) is mostly single-threaded. Hence, building the library for multiple ABIs in parallel helped shorten my build times a lot.

When building with CMake / Ninja I cannot replicate this behavior. Ninja is supposed to parallelize builds by default, and it may well be doing that for a given ABI (i.e. compiling multiple source files in parallel *for the same ABI*). But from what I can tell, it never starts building the library for another ABI until it has finished building for the current ABI.

---

**Question**

When using CMake / Ninja through `externalNativeBuild`, is there any way I can tell the build system that I want it to build my native code for multiple ABIs in parallel?

---

**Example**

A minimal example to demonstrate this is as simple as the "New project" template in Android Studio, i.e. something like:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(native-lib SHARED
            src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )
```

app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cmakemultiabis"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

And then building with e.g. `gradlew assembleRelease` will give you:

```
> Task :app:externalNativeBuildRelease
Build native-lib x86
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\x86\libnative-lib.so
Build native-lib armeabi-v7a
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi-v7a\libnative-lib.so
```

It may not be obvious from that output that the two libraries are built sequentially, but it does become obvious if you have something that takes a noticeable amount of time to link.

I have tried this both with the CMake / Ninja versions that you can download with the SDK Manager, as well as some newer versions (CMake 3.12.3, Ninja 1.8.2), and saw the same behavior in both cases.

Comment: With all due respect, I would suggest to give up on this quest. Note that the same 'anti-parallel' behavior will happen with **ndk-build** when run from **externalNativeBuild**. Instead of running `ndk-build -j`, gradle will sequentially build each ABI version. But there is little gain you get with parallel build for all ABIs. It's nice to have integrated C++ build in your project, but only for the the debugging purposes. That's why I only build all ABIs together on  Jenkins, and I don't use gradle integration there. Note: don't forget to split your APK!

Comment: _"But there is little gain you get with parallel build for all ABIs"_ For the average project, yes. But in my case it would cut the build time almost in half (because the bulk of the build time for each ABI variant is spent running the 3rd party single-threaded tool that I mentioned).

Comment: *"there is little gain you get with parallel build for all ABIs"* not because parallelization is not efficient, but because it only makes sense to use integrated build for ABI you are currently debugging.

Comment: Sure. I'd just like to avoid having to maintain two different solutions, or sticking with something that is outdated and perhaps ends up being removed in some future NDK release. Based on Google's Android documentation, `externalNativeBuild { cmake {}}` certainly seems like what they envision as the future.

Comment: I believe ndk-build is here to stay. And the CMake solution these days suffers from inconsistency between the 'native CMake Android support' and the 'CMake toolchain file' in NDK. But this doesn't really matter, CMake with Ninja will automatically perform parallel build. The problem is that Gradle runs each ABI sequentially. You can run same CMakeList.txt for all ABIs from command line.

Comment: Instead of looking for parallelism, why not leverage the use of build cache? I had a project which depends on a module that contained Native Code. That same module was cross platform and acted as an android-lib for the android project and an executable app as well. By including it as a module dependency, only the first build was needed to generate the lib aar-like artifacts and then whenever subsequent builds were executed things were retrieved from the cache (a log for `externalNativeBuildRelease` task would show something like "Nothing to do here") and hence build times were a lot shorter.

Comment: @ahasbini: For reasons I cannot disclose, the output of each build must be "unique" (not truly unique, but they should differ from one build to the next). So caching the output of previous builds isn't really an option.